# Having 2 HostBindings leading to class based on Inputs (Angular 4)

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have the following code in my component :

```
@Component({
selector: "home",
templateUrl: "./home.html"
})
export class Home {
    constructor() {}
    @HostBinding("class") @Input() public type: string = "alert"
    @HostBinding("class") @Input() public position: string = "top"
}
```

and the `main.html` :

```
<home></home>
```

`home.html` is empty

this isn't working as only `alert` is set as a class. How can I have both `alert` and `top` ?

Comment: what is the HTML looks like? two lines of code will not convey enough info

Comment: put html code here

Comment: Done, I really don't see what you want to see in there, but here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to do the following :

```
@Input() public type: string = "alert"
@Input() public position: string = "top"
@HostBinding("class") classes = this.type + " " + this.position
```